# Serializer returns object instead fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Using Django 2.1/Django Rest Framework.

I am receiving the Model object output from DRF instead of the actual fields.

I would like to recieve all the items for both the audio_links and release_artists tables.

Here's what I have.

**Output**

`{
    "title": "Attack The Dancefloor Volume Two",
    "audiolinks": [
        "AudioLinks object (55708)",
        "AudioLinks object (55709)",
        "AudioLinks object (55710)",
        "AudioLinks object (55711)"
    ],
    "releaseartists": [
        "ReleaseArtists object (140)",
        "ReleaseArtists object (141)"
    ]
}`

**models.py**

```
class AudioLinks(models.Model):
    release = models.ForeignKey('ReleasesAll', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='release_id', related_name='audiolinks')
    track_number = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'audio_links'

class ReleaseArtists(models.Model):
    release = models.ForeignKey('ReleasesAll', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='release_id', related_name='releaseartists')
    artists = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'release_artists'
```

**views.py**

```
class ListReleaseDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = ReleasesAll.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReleasesSerializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            a_release = self.queryset.prefetch_related('releaseartists','audiolinks').get(pk=kwargs['release_id'])
            return Response(ReleasesSerializer(a_release).data)

        except ReleasesAll.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data = {
                    "message": "{} does not exist".format(kwargs["release_id"])
                },
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ReleasesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    audiolinks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    releaseartists = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ReleasesAll
        fields = ('title','audiolinks','releaseartists')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`serializers.stringRelatedField` gives the output of the `__str__` method defined on the Model.

Hence you are getting this "`AudioLinks object (55708)`" and `ReleaseArtists object (141)`, which is the default `__str__` representation of any model.

In order to get all fields, you must define serializers for every other model that is related to the required fields as such:

```
class AudioLinksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AudioLinks
        fields = ('__all__')

class ReleaseArtistsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    audiolinks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    releaseartists = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ReleaseArtists
        fields = ('__all__')
```

and then:

```
class ReleasesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    audiolinks = AudioLinksSerializer(many=True)
    releaseartists = ReleaseArtistsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ReleasesAll
        fields = ('title','audiolinks','releaseartists')
```

That would do enough for you to get all fields.

***And also as of Django convention, you need to name the models as in singular form i.e, `AudioLink`, `ReleaseArtist`. This way you see the model as a single object. And it will be easier when you try to get `audiolinks` as you will be thinking like "there are many AudioLink objects and I am getting few of them"

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there a shortcut to output all the fields from ReleaseAll in the `ReleasesSerializer` class rather than typing them out manually? The equivalent of `fields = ('__all__','audiolinks','releaseartists')

Comment: No. `("__all__")` only works individually including the model fields, leaving aside related fields. So, if you want to include the related fields too, then you must add them individually. No workaround here.